# Why won't jQueryUI run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is for a WP install which already has the jQuery core installed like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
```

I want to utilize:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js

I've tried loading it in the body like this:

```
<div id="diag1">Step1</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js">

  alert("I'm alive"); // nope it's dead
  jQuery("#diag1").dialog({modal: true});

</script>
```

This does nothing not even if I put an alert in the page.

I've tried

- putting the script link in the head of the page as well.
- installing a 3rd party plugin which I know uses jqueryui and this does nothing.

I've verified

- jqueryui is loaded after jquery when I go to view->source
- jqueryui is compatible with jquery

What else can I do?

I know wordpress has a custom php function for loading script but I don't know what it does or how it effects script availability.  I tried using it and still no go.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

I just want to develop a modal using jQueryUI.  In the end that is all I'm trying to do:

For this site:

www.papermepress.com

Comment: I think you're wrapping it wrong. The tag with a `src` already points to a script. You need a new script tag to write the script you have up there.

Comment: You need a separate script block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't put anything between the script blocks as you need to close the reference to jQuery UI. So....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js">
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  alert("I'm alive"); // nope it's dead
  jQuery("#diag1").dialog({modal: true});

</script>
```

Comment: I must be some kind of fool thinking that I could put javaScript inside the JavaScript tags...WTF?  I don't want to understand why this works.

Comment: Yeah I've been caught out with this before. Also short closing <script /> tags is one to watch out for.

Comment: If you have a src attribute then the code should be in an external file. No src attribute then you're good to insert code into the block.

Comment: Thanks - glad to have helped.

Comment: and HTML is Tool...forgot to express my innerChild();